# C# datetime formatting discussion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, date-format

Every day someone on SO ask question about datetime formatting in c#. Is it okay to ask question and answer it myself with all possible options of formatting or better add this to tag wiki page?

When i seaching for 'datetime formating' i found many answers and can't find best one that can help me. And i suppose that newbie guys not looking into wiki page. *So reason why i asking is close all 'datetime formatting' questions in c# tag.*

What do you think about that?

Comment: Wouldn't your answer/wiki just be a straight copy of the information available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)? I don't think that replicating msdn is going to help. People are asking questions because they didn't read or understand the docs. Posting more docs won't help.

Comment: I will not post whole msdn page, i am speaking about short formats table, and three or four examples for *Date.Parse* and *Date.ParseExact*. And for sure links to msdn, and some other useful recources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to close *all* date and time formatting questions via one answer, because they won't *all* be needing the same thing.

For example, two questions which sound similar but have radically different "good" answers:

- How should I format my DateTime to display it to a user?
- How should I format my DateTime to include it in a database query?

In the second case, the best answer is "don't include the DateTime in your SQL to start with; use a parameterized query" - but that's completely irrelevant to the first question (which would need to find out about the user's culture etc).

I think it's reasonable to pick a well-asked question, write a comprehensive answer to *just that question* and then close very similar questions as duplicates. I don't think this belongs in the tag wiki, but a *link* to that question could belong in the tag wiki.

(I've been considering writing "hopefully definitive" questions for very common concerns in the same way.)

Comment: Thanks, i see your point. +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own answer that merge the best answers to one active question (that wasn't closed as duplicate) then point people to that answer of yours when you see new questions on this topic.

If you see old question you think should be closed as duplicate you can Flag it for moderator attention specifying what is the duplicate question. If you're not sure it's duplicate, feel free to ask here. :)